Python converting string to array
I'm recently tring to make a python code to convert a string to array.
For example:
'[[M,,[10,20]],[F,,[7,9]]]' to [['M','',['10','20']],['F','',['7','9']]]
The reason I need it is that I am importing data from excel, which contains arrays in some of the cells, but I have absolutely no idea how to do that, and I would be very grateful if anyone could give me some hint.
I tried to ask chatGPT, but it gave me a code that did not work. Here is the code:
def parse_string(s):
    result = []
    current_list = []
    i = 0

    while i < len(s):
        char = s[i]
        if char == '[':
            inner_result, remaining_string = parse_string(s[i + 1:])
            current_list.append(inner_result)
            i += len(inner_result) + 2  
        elif char == ']':
            result.append(current_list)
            return result, s[i + 1:]
        elif char == ',':
            if i > 0 and s[i - 1] == ',':
                current_list.append('')
            i += 1
        elif char.isalnum() or char == '.':
            j = i
            while j < len(s) and (s[j].isalnum() or s[j] == '.' or s[j] == '-'):
                j += 1
            current_list.append(s[i:j])
            i = j
        else:
            i += 1

    return result, ''

string = '[[M,,[10,20]],[F,,[7,9]]]'
result, _ = parse_string(string)
print(result)


And the result would be like: [[[[[['M', '', [['10', '20']], '20']], '', [['10', '20']], '20']], '', [['10', '20']], '20']]

Try the How to debug small programs guide?

Not tested but maybe ast.literal_eval could be helpul in this case if you want to google for it

You can achieve this conversion using Python's ast module, which provides functions to safely evaluate Python expressions from strings containing Python literal structures.
Here is the code:
import ast

def convert_string_to_array(s):
    s = s.replace('M', "'Male'").replace('F', "'Female'")
    array = ast.literal_eval(s)
    return array

s = '[[M,,[10,20]],[F,,[7,9]]]'
result = convert_string_to_array(s)
print(result)


We'll also need to handle the double commas...

Could you explain why you do str.replace() for M and F?

Yes good question! Why not 'Fig' and 'Mango' ?

I've tried ast module
import ast

def convert_string_to_array(s):

    i=0

    while i<=len(s)-1:
        # Dealing the double comma issue
        if s[i]==',' and s[i+1]==',':
            s=s[:i+1]+"''"+s[i+1:]

        # Replace the string within the array with 'string'
        if s[i].isalpha() is True and s[i-1].isalpha() is False and s[i-1]!="'":
            i_head=i
        if s[i].isalpha() is True and s[i+1].isalpha() is False and s[i+1]!="'":
            i_tail=i
            s=s.replace(s[i_head:i_tail+1],f"'{s[i_head:i_tail+1]}'")

        i+=1
        print(i)


    array = ast.literal_eval(s)
    return array

s = '[[M,,[10,20]],[F,,[7,9]]]'
result = convert_string_to_array(s)
print(result)

The result would be [['M', '', [10, 20]], ['F', '', [7, 9]]]
This piece of code is modified based on Mr. Aryan Chauhan and Mr.Friedrich's code.
For the double comma issue, I added a empty string between the two commas.
Given the possibility of other strings appearing within the array, I've used isalpha() method to detect the string and convert it into f"'{string}'".
